# How to detect if your mouse is over a GameObject's Box Collider 2D and not it's Image using IPointer? [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a card game, and I'm trying to make it so when you hover over a Pack of Cards' Box Collider 2D, it'll switch to a different image, and will do the same but with a different image when you stop hovering over it.

However, IPointerEnter/Exit aren't detecting if it's over the object's collider, but rather when it's over the object itself, which is a problem because the sprites need to be bigger than the image itself.

I've looked all over Reddit and Stackoverflow and nobody's previous answers have lead to a result that works in my instance, mostly due to the fact that IPointer doesn't automatically reference a collider like OnMouseEnter/Exit did. I've tried a couple of things but nothing has worked so far, so any advice would be super helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a script to your Pack of Cards GameObject named `CardHoverDetector`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CardHoverDetector : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;

    private void Start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // Check if the mouse position is within the BoxCollider2D bounds
        if (boxCollider != null && boxCollider.bounds.Contains(eventData.position))
        {
            // Mouse is over the BoxCollider2D
            // Add your code to switch to a different image here
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // Check if the mouse position is outside the BoxCollider2D bounds
        if (boxCollider != null && !boxCollider.bounds.Contains(eventData.position))
        {
            // Mouse is outside the BoxCollider2D
            // Add your code to switch back to the original image here
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `OnPointerEnter`, we check if the mouse position is within the bounds of the BoxCollider2D. If it is, you can add your code to switch to a different image.